# How to have a top left navigation cancel button, for a UIViewController created from XIB?

Tags: ios, swift

In Stroyboard, it is pretty straightforward to embed a `UIViewController` in a Navigation Controller, then subsequently able to add a UIBarButtonItem cancel button, for unwind purpose.

But, I was wondering, how do we do that, if our `UIViewController` is created from XIB?

I have the following custom view, which present modal `UIViewController`.

```
class CustomColorView: UIView {
    @objc func textViewWasTapped() {
        let hexColorStringInputVC = HexColorStringInputVC.instanceFromNib()
        
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: hexColorStringInputVC)

        // Cancel button not visible. Not sure why?!
        navController.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: self, action: nil), animated: true)
        
        UIViewController.topViewController()?.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    ...
}

extension UIViewController {
    static func instanceFromNib() -> Self {
        func instantiateFromNib<T: UIViewController>() -> T {
            return T.init(nibName: String(describing: T.self), bundle: nil)
        }

        return instantiateFromNib()
    }
    
    static func topViewController() -> UIViewController? {
        let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first
        
        guard var top = keyWindow?.rootViewController else {
            return nil
        }
        
        while let next = top.presentedViewController {
            top = next
        }
        
        return top
    }
}
```

---

When `textViewWasTapped` executed, it looks as following.

[image]

1. Is embedded `UIViewController` within a `UINavigationController` required?
2. Why top left cancel button is not visible via `navController.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton`?
3. How to add unwind operation to navigation cancel button?
4. Is there an easier to do it in XIB, just as easy as Storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Is embedded UIViewController within a UINavigationController required?

It depends what you wanna do. If you don't want to create custom view with manually added `UINavigationBar` then this is the easiest way to get `UINavigationBar` in your view.

2. Why top left cancel button is not visible via `navController.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton`?

As explained in [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller):

> A navigation controller builds the contents of the navigation bar dynamically using the navigation item objects (instances of the UINavigationItem class) associated with the view controllers on the navigation stack. To customize the overall appearance of a navigation bar, use UIAppearance APIs. To change the contents of the navigation bar, you must therefore configure the navigation items of your custom view controllers. For more information about navigation items, see UINavigationItem.

This means that you must add `UIBarButtonItem` to your `UIViewController` instance instead of `UINavigationController` instance. In your example this would be:

```
hexColorStringInputVC.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: self, action: nil), animated: true)
```

3. How to add unwind operation to navigation cancel button?

If you mean with "unwind operation" navigating back to parent view controller who presented current child view controller modally then you must use [`dismiss(animated:completion:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismiss) method on your child view controller. In your example this would be:

```
...
hexColorStringInputVC.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: self, action: #selector(cancelButtonPressed)), animated: true)
...
@objc func cancelButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarItem) {
    navController.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

Of course `navController` variable must be in scope.

If you have to pass data back and forth then there is many tutorials on this topic. I would suggest to start with delegation pattern.

4. Is there an easier to do it in XIB, just as easy as Storyboard?

If you mean with "easier" doing it in interface builder with proxy objects then no.

When I'm creating main view for view controller in xib file I declare control action methods in his view controller.